# Why can't I see my flash drive when I try to import my pgp key?

Tags: tails

Recently updated 2.10...I don't understand why every flash drive I plug in doesn't show up. I have my key saved on my flash drives.

Comment: Does it appear at all? Does `lsusb` show anything and what kind of filesystem did you format it to use?